# basement bathroom flooring options in old 1929 house

Tags: bathroom, concrete, basement, tile, vinyl

I have an old house built in 1929 in Minneapolis, Mn.  I need to replace water damaged rotted basement bathroom floor(toilet and shower leak another story). Current floor is 2" by 4" sleepers set on concrete with either treated plywood or cement board(not sure haven't pulled up yet) and vinyl on top. I want to replace the floor but I need to do it on the cheap because I'm 40k undervalued in this house.  I'm also assuming the original cement floor under all this is in rough shape.

What are my options?

Comment: Why wouldn't the standard plywood subfloor be your go-to choice?

Comment: I'd go with tile which a) fits the era b) doesn't have to be expensive (hit up the ReUse center) and c) a good material for damp areas (baths/basements)

Answer (score 1):

Your options are pretty much infinite. I'd favor gypcrete to raise, level and provide a nice base, then tile. Nothing to rot when the next leak happens (it's a bathroom, there will always be a next leak.) I'd also put radiant floor heat tubing in place in the gypcrete pour, and if there's enough room for sleepers (now), XPS [extruded polystyrene] insulation on top of the concrete floor, under the gypcrete with radiant floor tubing in it.

If the present floor is rotted, it's probably not cementboard - that doesn't rot.